# MySQL SELECT statement returns no record when I am searching with a value that contains hyphen(-)

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

Problematic Query:

```
 SELECT * FROM my_links WHERE taxonomy='ait-dir-item-category'
```

Above query returns no record and no error.
I am getting empty result, but I have exactly same value '**ait-dir-item-category**' for taxonomy column. 
But following query returns result

Perfect Query:

```
 SELECT * FROM my_links WHERE taxonomy='post_tag'
```

Please tell me what is the problem.

Comment: Compare `LENGTH()` of your 'ait-dir-item-category' and actual field value. It might be a whitespace there.

Comment: Or, rather than whitespace, it could be different characters than `-` hyphens. Could be ndash or mdash...

Comment: My issue resolved. It was my mistake, My field length was 1 character less then my value.
So it is not issue with hyphen(-)

Answer (score -1):

Try with LIKE statment

```
  SELECT * FROM my_links WHERE taxonomy LIKE '%ait-dir-item-category%'
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried using like statement
Can you try like this,

```
select * from my_link where taxonomy like '%ait-dir-item%'
```